# Proving that $A$ is a Noetherian ring when $M$ is a faithful Noetherian $A$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noetherian

Let $M$ be a Noetherian $A$-module (where $A$ is a commutative ring).

I want to show that $M$ is faithful implies $A$ is Noetherian.

I am very aware that this question is fully answered in both of these posts:

[If $M$ is Noetherian, then $R/\text{Ann}(M)$ is Noetherian, where $M$ is an $R$-module](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763433/)

[Let $M$ be a noetherian $R$-module and $I=\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)$. Then $R/I$ is a noetherian ring.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726261/)

But I would really like to try and get my (naive) method below to work (if possible). So I would be very grateful if anyone could help me make the following idea work...

---

Suppose $A$ is not Noetherian. Then we can find a chain of ideals

$$I_1\subsetneq I_2 \subsetneq \ldots$$

My idea is to lift this to a strictly increasing chain of submodules of $M.$

Naturally, my first thought is to consider the chain

$$I_1M\subseteq I_2M \subseteq \ldots$$

Can I prove this is strictly increasing?

Well suppose that $I\subsetneq J$ are ideals of $A.$

Take $y \in J\setminus I$ and consider the $A$-linear map $\phi:M\to M$ given by

$$\phi(m)=ym.$$

If $JM=IM,$ then (by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem) we have a relation

$$\phi^n+a_1\phi^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n\mathrm{id}_M=0$$

where the $a_i$ belong to $I.$ Since $M$ is faithful, it follows that

$$y^n+a_1y^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n=0$$

and hence we have shown that $y^n \in I$ which is not quite what we wanted. I then thought perhaps I could take radicals of the original chain of ideals and then apply the above result but of course the process of taking radicals does not necessarily preserve strict inclusion and so I'm a bit stuck now...

Comment: The fact that you are stuck suggests me that this is a wrong way.

Comment: But in this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572711/ user52045's comment on the OP's question says that the result I want is true but supplies no proof. Any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: If he said so... Let's suppose $IM=JM$. Then $(J/I)(M/IM)=0$. If we want $J/I=0$ then $\mathrm{Ann}_{R/I}(M/IM)=0$. I have [serious doubts](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/79548/310443) that the annihilator of $M/IM$ equals $I$.

Comment: Sorry, why must $J/I=0$ imply that $\mathrm{Ann}_{R/I}(M/IM)=0$? Of course, I agree that $J/I \subseteq \mathrm{Ann}_{R/I}(M/IM)$ but...?

Comment: Actually I had to write it like this: If $\mathrm{Ann}_{R/I}(M/IM)\ne 0$ then there is $a\in R$, $a\notin I$ such that $a(M/IM)=0$, that is, $aM\subseteq IM$. Now set $J=I+(a)$, and notice that $IM=JM$, but $I\subsetneq J$. This means that the condition $\mathrm{Ann}_{R/I}(M/IM)\ne 0$ provides two ideals $I,J$ contradicting your claim. But $\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)=0$ is not enough to conclude $\mathrm{Ann}_{R/I}(M/IM)=0$, as the linked example shows, so your argument can't lead to a proof.

Comment: Ah okay! Many thanks. I also understand your counterexample in the link you posted. Thank you for your help :)